# как установить кастомное view в Viewpager2

Tags: android, kotlin

я хочу добавить кастомное view в ViewPager2, но получаю NPE
вот мой код
**Кастомное вью**

```
class PlaceView : FrameLayout {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyleAttr
    )

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet?,
        defStyleAttr: Int,
        defStyleRes: Int
    ) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyleAttr,
        defStyleRes
    )

    private val headerView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.viewPagerHeader)
    private val imageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.viewPagerImage)
    private val urlView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.viewPagerTextUrl)
    private val addressView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.viewPagerTextPlace)

    var header: String? = ""
        set(value) {
            field = value
            headerView.text = value
        }

    var imageResource: Int? = null
        set(value) {
            field = value
            imageResource?.let { imageView.setImageResource(it) }
        }

    var url: String? = ""
        set(value) {
            field = value
            urlView.text = url
        }

    var address: String? = ""
        set(value) {
            field = value
            addressView.text = address
        }

}
```

**Адаптер vp2**

```
class ViewPagerAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewPagerHolder>() {

    var values: List<PlacesModel?> = listOf()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewPagerHolder {

        val view: View =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.viewpageritem, parent, false)
        return parent.context.viewPagerHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = PlacesFilter.TAKES_PLACES


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewPagerHolder, position: Int) {
        val request = values[position]?.properties?.responseMetadata?.searchRequest?.request
        val found = values[position]?.properties?.responseMetadata?.searchResponse?.found
        var name: String? = ""
        var description: String? = ""
        var url: String? = "Данные отсутсвуют"

        //если элементы найдены
        if (found != 0) {

            val properties = values[position]?.features?.get(0)?.properties
            name = properties?.name
            description = properties?.description

            if (properties?.companyMetaData != null) {
                url = properties.companyMetaData.url
            }
        }

        holder.bind(
            name,
            MAIN_DICTIONARY[request] ?: R.drawable.empty,
            url,
            description
        )
    }
}
```

**холдер для vp2**

```
class ViewPagerHolder(
    private val view: View,
    private var placeView:PlaceView
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    fun bind(header: String?, image: Int, info: String?, address: String?) {
        placeView.header = header
        placeView.imageResource = image
        placeView.url = info
        placeView.address = address


    }
}


fun Context.viewPagerHolder(view: View): ViewPagerHolder {
    return ViewPagerHolder(
        view,
        view.findViewById(R.id.placeViewItem)
    )
}
```

**viewpageritem.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ru.skillbranch.places.component.PlaceView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/placeViewItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</ru.skillbranch.places.component.PlaceView>
```

*** и мой стек ***

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ru.skillbranch.places, PID: 8628
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: headerView must not be null
        at ru.skillbranch.places.component.PlaceView.setHeader(PlaceView.kt:44)
        at ru.skillbranch.places.screens.mainScreen.presentation.view.ViewPagerHolder.bind(ViewPagerHolder.kt:22)
        at ru.skillbranch.places.screens.mainScreen.presentation.view.ViewPagerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ViewPagerAdapter.kt:45)
        at ru.skillbranch.places.screens.mainScreen.presentation.view.ViewPagerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ViewPagerAdapter.kt:12)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3540)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23196)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChild(ViewGroup.java:6724)
        at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.onMeasure(ViewPager2.java:498)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23196)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23196)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6753)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23196)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23196)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6753)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23196)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6753)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23196)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6753)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23196)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6753)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23196)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6753)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:720)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23196)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2796)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1644)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1928)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1532)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7419)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1092)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:888)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:819)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1078)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

Comment: Вам нужно инфлейтить R.layout.place_view в вашем кастомном вью PlaceView. Когда вы вызываете findViewById<TextView>(R.id.viewPagerHeader), то его не находит и headerView == null

Comment: @Circassian не могли бы вы разъяснить подробнее или привести пример

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в ваш PlaceView

```
init {
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.place_view, this)
}
```

UPD

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = 
        ViewPagerHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.viewpageritem, parent, false)
        )
```

Вьюхолдер должен быть такой, ведь `placeViewItem` является единственным элементом в `viewpageritem`

```
class ViewPagerHolder(
        private val view: View
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    fun bind(header: String?, image: Int, info: String?, address: String?) {
        (view as? PlaceView)?.apply {
            this.header = header
            this.imageResource = image
            this.url = info
            this.address = address
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: данная реализация зацикливает приложение

Comment: Почему у вас в onBindViewHolder столько вычислений? Adapter не должен этого делать. Согласно принципу S он должен лишь рендерить элементы списка. Все вычисления делаете вне адаптера и отдаете ему готовый список с моделями

Comment: это из-за не знания,спасибо, но 
init {
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.place_view, this)
}
все еще приводит к зацикливанию приложения

Comment: Ищите проблему в адаптере. У вас вопрос был почему ловите NPE, я ответил

Comment: в разметке placeVIew я использовал этот же placeView, что и приводило к зацикливанию, вопрос закрыт